# Hanging Query when joining multiple tables and counting rows

Tags: mysql, join, count, freeze

I'm trying to write a query that will generate a list of merchants and then a count of how many Inventory Items they have and how many orders exist for each of them. Merchants, Inventory Items and Orders are all in different tables. I'm expecting the return to look like this:

```
Site    | Inventory Items | Orders
London  | 7282            | 1234996
Glasgow | 9829            | 734949
```

I can get the list of Site and Inventory count almost instantly with this query:

```
SELECT M.name AS 'Site',
       COUNT(II.idInventoryItems) AS 'Inventory Items',
FROM Merchants M
JOIN
  (SELECT idMerchants,
          idInventoryItems
   FROM InventoryItems) AS II ON II.idMerchants = M.idMerchants
GROUP BY M.name
```

And I can get a list of Site and Orders with a very similar query. But when I combine the two the query hangs indefinitely and I have to cancel the query. Here is the complete query I've been using:

```
SELECT M.name AS 'Site',
       COUNT(II.idInventoryItems) AS 'Inventory Items',
       COUNT(O.idOrders) AS 'Orders'
FROM Merchants M
JOIN
  (SELECT idMerchants,
          idInventoryItems
   FROM InventoryItems) AS II ON II.idMerchants = M.idMerchants
JOIN
  (SELECT idMerchants,
          idOrders
   FROM Orders) AS O ON O.idMerchants = M.idMerchants
GROUP BY M.name
```

Is what I'm trying to do achievable with a reasonably fast query? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the indexes?

Comment: Also, Do you really need to use subqueries at all? couldn't you simply join with Orders and InventoryItems? As far as I know, MySQL isn't really optimized regarding subqueries

Comment: @Sebastianb Subqueries are necessary here due to the 1:M relationships between `M` and `II` and `M` and `O`.  The Many-to-Many which occurs between `Orders` and `InventoryItems` will artificially increase the counts providing incorrect counts; thus the subqueries need to get the counts 1st and then join.  Which is why I believe Chris's answer would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.  Moving the count to the derived table will give you the data you need for the join and allow mysql to optimize with an index on idMerchants if it needs it for performance purposes.  You will then be joining with two derived tables with significantly fewer rows which will improve the performance as well.

```
SELECT M.name AS 'Site',
   II.count AS 'Inventory Items',
   O.count as 'Orders'
FROM Merchants M
JOIN
  (SELECT idMerchants, COUNT(idInventoryItems) AS 'count'
   FROM InventoryItems GROUP BY idMerchants) AS II ON II.idMerchants = M.idMerchants
JOIN
  (SELECT idMerchants,
      COUNT(idOrders) AS 'count'
   FROM Orders GROUP BY idMerchants) AS O ON O.idMerchants = M.idMerchants
```

Comment: Chris, i agree that this would work but explaining your answer in addition to the SQL would be beneficial.

Comment: Nice update.  The why is just as, and sometimes more important, than the how.  Note that if they don't do it, the counts would be incorrect inflated by the M:M between II and O.  Might be able to resolve if a distinct on the count is used, but then they wouldn't benefit from the performance gain you mention.

Comment: I left the group by M.name but not sure if the OP will still need it??  Probably needs to be removed since not aggregating at that level any longer.

Comment: Answer edited to remove the superfluous "group by name"

Comment: That's awesome! It worked really fast and was exactly what I was looking for. I have been having a similar issue with other queries hanging so I'm going to see if I can use the explanation from this answer to fix my other ones too. Thank you very much :)